# Meld points in a double deck pinochle game

Tags: pinochle

In a double deck game of pinochle jacks around is worth 4 points. Queens around is worth 6 points. A pinochle ( jack of diamond, queen of spade) is worth 4 point. Therefore when you have queens and jacks around your total point score is 14. However, when another jack of diamond and a queen of spade is added to the mix, creating a double pinochle worth 30 points, what would be the total points awarded for a double pinochle with queens and jacks around?

Answer (score 1):

You would have 6 points for the Queens, 4 points for the Jacks, and 30 points for the double pinochle, for a total of 40 points.

This is really no different than the single pinochle case that you list; you just have 30 points instead of 4 for the pinochle points, so 26 more points than your first example.